# OpenUI5 app with no shell

Tags: sapui5

I know you can do OpenUI5 apps with no shell, just using `sap.m.App`, but SAP provides no documentation on this.  I am at a loss as to how to get the `Component.js` loaded, as `sap.m.App` does not have the option of `app: new ComponentContainer` that the tutorial say to use when using `sap.m.Shell`.  I need this to get routing setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define a ComponentContainer on your own. For example you can put this into an index.html and start your app through this page, like described in the Walkthrough https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/4cfa60872dca462cb87148ccd0d948ee.html

scroll down until you see the code of the index.html file